# Generate Java code from a diagram model

Tags: java, eclipse, graph, code-generation, decision-tree

In my application, I model a decision diagram (nodes+connections). I have model classes ready (two basic classes: `Node` and `Connection` + subclasses for special cases). This diagram gets very big and keeping track of all the connections and nodes only through code is not easy (and take into account future maintenance). I was wondering if there's a tool (Eclipse plugin or other) that I could feed with my model classes (i.e. types of nodes, types of connections), use it to "draw" the diagram graphically (making nodes and connections) and then generate the code of the diagram?

Model classes:
`Node`: contains `List<Connection>` of all connections FROM this node
`Connection`: `Node from`, `Node to`

**EDIT:**
I want to generate a method that initializes all the needed nodes and connections (`Node` and `Connection` objects) and returns the head/start node. This in-memory structure is then traversed by the application when it makes decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds a bit like you want something like jgraph? http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html

Comment: no - but i'm not sure why you would really want to do that. You are building up a data structure representing some kind of graph. Generally you might need to store / persist the graph in some kind of serialised form, but that form is rarely java code.

Comment: Thats not to say it can't be done of course! - Just serialise your data structure into java.

Comment: I want to convert it to java code because this diagram is then used to make decisions - it's a decision diagram. I choose a start node and then traverse the graph until reaching an end node.

Comment: thats an in memory data structure that you traverse. you don't traverse the java code, though. how you build up the structure doesn't matter, you can build it up from code, or build it up from a gui, or from a serialised form.. its still an in-memory data structure

Comment: Exactly, but I want to build this structure graphically (by drawing the diagram) and then generate a method that initializes all the objects (nodes and connections) and returns the start node. Any advice as how to do this?

Comment: i'm not sure i can add much detail to that i already said. maybe doing all this graphically is a bit of a big leap. try building the structure simply first, using a text input file. then once you get the hang of that, then use a gui builder. note that a gui is probably the most difficult way to build this data structure!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/docs/index.html)

AndroMDA (pronounced: andromeda) is an open source code generation framework that follows the Model Driven Architecture (MDA) paradigm. It takes model(s) from CASE-tool(s) and generates fully deployable applications and other components.

If you can create your graph using some UML tools(not sure how easy that would be) AndroMDA can generate the java code for you.

It supports many [UML tools](http://www.andromda.org/docs/case-tools.html) including some free tools.

Answer (score 0):

Tale a look on [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). It is widely used for code generation.

Answer (score 0):

You might like [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). It is  very easy to build a directional graph diagram in that application. There are several wrapper libraries to help integrating it if you want to do that. Or if you just want to feed the graph and generate a picture, this is very straightforward. Check out the examples [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).
FTW: I have used this extensively for class hierarchies, interaction flow description, mind maps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also interested in GENERATING code based on the diagram. Graphviz doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: aah, crap! I read it wrong. Sorry, I guess velocity is one of the options.

Comment: The only ones, I know of, that do diagramming and code genreation are UML based tools.http://www.altova.com/umodel.html and http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/ Not sure if you are interested in them.. or not.